# Higher score to exact PrefixQuery

Tags: java, lucene

I always want to give exact matches a higher score than those that just match a prefix (e.g. "ball" should give a higher score when matched against "ball*" than "ballistic").

My current (verbose) approach is to always do two lines instead of one when creating a `PrefixQuery`, e.g.

```
q.add(new PrefixQuery(new Term("field", t)), Occur.SHOULD);
q.add(new TermQuery(new Term("field", t)), Occur.SHOULD);
```

is there a way to achive the same score without having to do this?

Comment: There are a better way consist in set to each vocal and consonant a value, ofr example a =1 b=2 etc... and compare with the score of the principal words, this have the problem that diferents vocal and consonat have summ the same, but you can do a more dificult system to puntuate the word, for example you can multiply for a constant if they are similar consonats and vocal next to other. For example with this method ball score is better tahn allb score but this is better than albl. It is better to set diferent scores to each letter (even studing the kind ok keyboard that you are using).

Comment: Continue: It is better to set different scores to each letter acording to the position in the keyborad because if easy to put a "a" instead a "s" but is not so commun to put "o" instead "a". Then in summary the best way is to do a math system acording the position the consonant and vocals and the mistakes that someone could do.

Comment: @Deckard27 what you're saying is not relevant for my use case. This isn't necessarilly user input.

Comment: I know that, it is only an example, i said that for scored matches the best way is to do a math system, acording to the complexity or the system you can obtein more reliable scores. I remember a friend taht do something similar and won a prize in an european contest, i will try to find the article and give you the link.

Comment: @Deckard27 this is specifically a Lucene question ;-) I really do *just* need the score modified the way I'm requesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's pretty much the standard method to achieve what you are looking for.  Similarly, you see patterns like `field:term* field:term^2` crop up when using the query parser a fair bit as well.

If you find yourself recreating this logic a lot, I'd just create a custom prefix query to use, something along the lines of:

```
public class MyPrefixQuery extends BooleanQuery {
    public MyPrefixQuery(Term t){
        add(new PrefixQuery(t), Occur.SHOULD);
        add(new TermQuery(t), Occur.SHOULD);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's more or less what I did: but you have confirmed that what I'm doing is sensible. Thanks :-)